# What lengths are best for logarithm sticks?

Tags: probability

To demonstrate the logarithm rule $\log(x) + \log(y) = \log(xy)$ to students, I have a pile of 70 sticks of various lengths. Each one is labeled with a number $N$, and the length of that stick is $\log(N)$ feet. The result in class is that if students put stick $M$ and stick $N$ end-to-end, they see that it is the same length as the stick labeled $MN$.

I usually grab 8 random sticks from the pile and pass them out to a group of students, hoping that there is a "hit" in those 8 sticks -- at least one triple $(M, N, MN)$ that demonstrates the relation.

The question: **What numbers should I use to maximize the chances of a "hit" (M, N, MN) when 8 numbers are chosen?**

The restrictions:

- The numbers must be positive integers at least 2, and no more than 10000 -- I need to store the sticks in my office.
- I would like there to be a lot of distinct "hits": triples $(M, N, MN)$. For example although the answer "choose half 10s and half 100s" makes it very likely for the students to see a "hit" in their pile, it also isn't very interesting.
- I need to make about 70 of these sticks so I have enough for an entire classroom.

For example one possible answer is "Start with a large number that has many factors, say 7200, then make all the other numbers factors of this number." But it's not clear to me how to measure the likelihood of a hit in this case, or if this is even a good idea.

Please try to focus on the math question here and not the pedagogical motivation. Thank you!

Comment: You mentioned that the "half 10, half 100" answer isn't very interesting -- fair enough. But are you opposed to similar games, such as "one-third 10, one-third 100, one-third 1000"? How about "10, 100, 1000, 10000" each occupying a quarter of the stack? Any bright lines here for you?

Comment: I suppose my second restriction means that I want to maximize both the probability of getting a "hit" and the number of distinct "hits" available. You will likely not be able to maximize both at the same time, but I would be interested in solutions that maximize either measure, or some combination of the two. In this way, I'm not really interested in "10,100,1000,10000" either -- there are only four distinct "hits:" $(10,10,100), (10,100,1000), (10,1000,10000), (100,100,10000)$.

Comment: What is the minimum length ? $\log(2)$ feet ?

Comment: It seems like taking the first six prime numbers: $2,3,5,7,11,13$ and then all pairs ($2\times 3$, $2\times 5$, etc.) and then all triples, and so on should give you around about 80 sticks of reasonable length for which your worst case scenario would be pulling the six shortest plus two others.  I haven't worked it out rigorously though.  (And is there a reason for choosing feet over metres, given that metres are an SI unit?)

Comment: Sure, let's stick with positive integers $n \geq 2$ -- editing now.

Comment: The reason to choose feet over metres is that if you choose metres, then the stick labeled $100$ is already too long to store in my office @postmortes .